# XSLT - replace reoccuring parts of XML document (at any level)

Tags: xslt

pros, 
I need to convert the 'B' tag with 'X' tag in the following document:

```
<a>
 <B marker="true">
  <c>
    <B marker="true">
      <d>
        <B marker="true">
        </B>
       <d>
    </B>
  </c>
 </B>
</a>
```

Note the reoccurring 'B', it can appear at any depth in dynamic XML.
Here's what I did:

```
<xsl:template match="//*[@marker='true']">
    <X>
        <xsl:copy-of select="./node()"/>
    </X>
</xsl:template>
```

It worked for the top-most 'B' tag, but ignored all the nested ones.

I think I know what the problem is - 'copy-of' just flushes the content of the top-most 'B' tag, without evaluating it. What can I do to make 'copy-of' reevaluate my template?

Thanks!
Baruch.

Comment: see my answer, exploiting basic "identity tranform" pattern.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would go with identity transform.

This code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="B[@marker = 'true']">
        <X>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </X>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Against this XML input:

```
<a>
    <B marker="true">
        <c test="test">
            testText
            <B marker="true">
                <d>
                    testText2
                    <B marker="true">
                        testText3
                    </B>
                </d>
            </B>
            testText4
        </c>
        testText5
    </B>
</a>
```

Will provide this correct result:

```
<a>
    <X>
        <c test="test">
            testText
            <X>
                <d>
                    testText2
                    <X>
                        testText3
                    </X>
                </d></X>
            testText4
        </c>
        testText5
    </X>
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks! I was in a middle of answering it myself with exactly that solution. Didn't know it has a name, though :)

Comment: Not like it's canonical one like "singleton" for example. I'm not a native speaker either, so name can vary. Glad I was helpful though :)

Comment: I tend to call it the "modified identity transform" pattern, in that the first template rule defines an identity transform, and the second template rule defines how the transform differs from an identity transform.

Comment: @Michael Kay, I prefer "identity transform with overrides", but it's the same.

Comment: I agree with @Flack: when talking about rules, one say that some rule overwrites another.